# How to add a new line in this script using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to output like this sample:

Apple

Banana

Cherry

But this script gave me this output:
Apple Banana Cherry

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {

    $(function() {
        $( ".listLi", ".rightSidebar" ).sort(function( a, b ) {
            return $( a ).text().toLowerCase() > $( b ).text().toLowerCase(); 

        }).appendTo( ".rightSidebar" );

    });

});
```

Comment: There is no difference between sample output and script output

Comment: I'd like to output like this sample:
<br />
Apple
<br />
Banana
<br />
Cherry....how to have a new line in jQuery?

Comment: Can you paste the HTML part of this code

Comment: <ul class= "rightSidebar">
<li class="listLi">Apple</li>
<li class="listLi">Banana</li>
<li class="listLi">Cherry</li>
</ul>